# Re-bind datagrid when window is closed

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have a data grid that displays data from a sql server. I have an add button, that when clicked it opens a new window where the user can put the information for the new item that is being added. When the user clicks save, the data is being saved to the database, but its not showing up the in the grid. Is there a way that I can make the datagrid bind when the add window is closed? Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

In my main window, that contains the datagrid code, i have an add button:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        showAddWindow();
}
```

And, the showAddWindow method is:

```
private void showAddWindow()
{
    add addWindow = new  add(dgDataView);
    addWindow.Owner = this;
    addWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    addWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What is your grid bound to? A `DataSet`? Or directly to db? Or what?

Comment: winforms and bound to a dataset

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Id of new inserted object, then you can send it to the main form, and call Add.Row on the grid with the new info. This way you'll not make a callback to the database for rebinding.

Comment: I'm voting this up becausse this would be wise if the data is a huge amount of data and performance is a factor. But this approach means adding additional code to read the values from the "Add" form and manually adding the row. It's a trade-off between simplicity and performance. Before taking this approach, I'd weigh the performance benefit against the added complexity, since added complexity means more chances for bugs (since we programmers are fallible humans).  My approach keeps the code simpler, but there is a chance for a performance issue if the form is pulling large amounts of data.

Comment: when the new item is added, it is assigned a new id. I am trying to keep this simple if possible, so I am trying to avoid more complexity by all means lol...however, i will do what i need to in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is WinForms:

First, when calling the "Add" window, use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) instead of Show()

In the main form with the DataGrid the code would look like

```
private void btnAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult b =    frmAdd.ShowDialog();
   if(b == DialogResult.Ok)
   {
    // code to re-bind the grid here.
   }
}
```

in the frmAdd form, you will need to make your Save button set the DialogResult for the form to be DialogResult.Ok after updating the database.

I'm guessing that what you have tried is along the lines of:
    private void btnAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAdd.ShowDialog();
        // code to re-bind the grid here.
    }

The difference is that with the ShowDialog() call, the main form will wait until the "add" form is closed to continue executing.  In my second code sample, just using Show(), the code to re-bind the grid happens immediately after showing the "Add" form, before the user gets a chance to update the data.

(note, I did that code off the top of my head, not in Visual Studio, so it may have mistakes)